# appendChild positioning with Greasemonkey

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey

I've been using appendChild to add elements to pages, but I'm not always happy with where they end up...  can someone explain to me how to put elements where I want them?

For example:

```
mytable.parentNode.appendChild (zNode, mytable);
```

places zNode (is zNode some official syntax or is it like everyone using 'i' as the variable in loops?) at the bottom of the table...

How do I put zNode at the TOP of the table instead?

For example... on [THIS PAGE](http://unicreatures.com/view_accomplishments.php?id=66219) How would I place the button between where it says how many accomplishments and the top of the table?

How would I attach something above, below, or to the right or left of an image or other element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[appendChild](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.appendChild) adds the node at the end.

To place a node before your table you can use [insertBefore](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.insertBefore):

```
mytable.parentNode.insertBefore(zNode, mytable);
```

To center a button you have to add `text-align: center` to the parent:

```
<div style="text-align: center;">
    <button>Click me</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you... it worked... the last script I tried it on didn't work though...  now to figure out how to center the button...  THANK YOU!

Comment: I was actually waiting to see if anyone answered the "above, below, right, left" part lol

Comment: Thats actually a question on its own. You might want to position the element absolute / fixed and then move it to the left/top of the target element's location relative to the document.

Comment: No easy 'align' like in html (at least I think there's 'align' in html)?

Comment: There are several ways to "align" stuff with HTML/CSS, which solution to use depends on the context. Could you work out an example in http://jsfiddle.net?

Comment: jsfiddle doesn't get along with dialup... unfortunately...  Say using the target page in my question here and the script in Brocks answer...  It puts the labels next to them, and on the last one in each row it puts it underneath because there isn't room... Say I wanted to put all the labels underneath (although I was thinking maybe a <br> in the text node might do that?

Comment: Or the button in this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19999634/greasemonkey-button-click-handler-not-working... no matter what I try I can't figure out how to center the darn thing... I was hoping I could find a tutorial somewhere that had a picture of a page showing the commands to put things in all the different places... but it doesn't seem to exist lol

Comment: You can center a button by setting the `text-align: center;` css property on the parent of the button.

Comment: I tried that!  in a GM_addStyle block... I also tried margin:0 auto and a couple other things.... it might be because my button seems to be in a created div... I don't know... it's not like the people who use my scripts care... I'm just a perfectionist lol...  Maybe I'll try to find the page that shows how to set it without GM_addStyle

Comment: Wait... on the 'parent' of the button?

Comment: Yes, I've updated my answer. Text-align tells an element how to align its inline children.

Comment: That WORKED!!!! THANK YOU!!!! grrrr... I was about to give up.... I wish there was a way to donate some rep to you... you went above and beyond on this!  Thank you!

Comment: Not a problem, always glad to help :)