# Greasemonkey button click handler not working?

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey, addeventlistener

So, I have this script that will grab the links off of the table on [THIS](http://unicreatures.com/view_accomplishments.php?id=66219) page (the 'x' are links on a logged in users page)...

So I'm trying to use a popup loop thing that Brock helped me with for another script...  the links get added properly into the 'linksToOpen' array (or did before I added the button, listener and 'openLinksInSequence' function)... everything seems to be fine and I get no error messages... but my button DOESN'T work!

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        Unicreatures Accoplishment Checker
// @namespace   http://trueidiocy.us
// @description Marks off completed accomplishments
// @include     http://unicreatures.com/accomplishments.php
// @include     http://www.unicreatures.com/accomplishments.php
// @include     http://unicreatures.com/accomplishments.php?
// @include     http://www.unicreatures.com/accomplishments.php?
// @version     1
// @grant       GM_addStyle
// ==/UserScript==

var mytable = document.getElementById('right').getElementsByTagName('table')[4];
var links=mytable.getElementsByTagName('a');
var i;
var linksToOpen     = [];
var mywin2          = null;


var zNode       = document.createElement ('div');
zNode.innerHTML = '<button id="checkButton" type="button">'
            + 'Check Accomplishments</button>'
            ;

zNode.setAttribute ('id', 'checkButton');

mytable.parentNode.insertBefore(zNode, mytable);



function checkAccomplishments (zEvent) {



for(i=0;i < links.length;i++) {
  if (links[i].href.indexOf('family') > -1) {


    linksToOpen.push (links[i].href);

    links[i].innerHTML="*";

}
}
alert(linksToOpen)

openLinksInSequence ();
};

function openLinksInSequence () {
    if (mywin2) {
        mywin2.close ();
        mywin2      = null;
    }

   if (linksToOpen.length) {
        var link    = linksToOpen.shift ();
        mywin2      = window.open (link, "my_win2");

        mywin2.addEventListener ('load', openLinksInSequence, false);
    }
}


checkButton.addEventListener ("click", checkAccomplishments, true);
```

So, why isn't my button working?

Comment: You have several problems, but most notably, you're setting the `id` of your div to the same as your button. And your trying to add the event listener to an undefined object. DOM elements don't show up as JS variables. You'd have to `var checkButton = document.getElementById("checkButton");` before you set the event listener.

Comment: but... but... but... I did it JUST like my working script... lol... I'll take a look at those issues... thanks

Comment: @mafafu That did it... thanks... if you add that as an answer I'll accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're setting the id of your div to the same as your button which is invalid. And your trying to add the event listener to an undefined object. DOM elements don't show up automatically as JS variables. You'd have to `var checkButton = document.getElementById("checkButton");` before you set the event listener.

Comment: Again... thank you... I knew it had to be something simple that I just wasn't seeing!